# bartMachine serialize compatibility between CPUs

Tags: r, bartmachine

When using bartMachine, if I create the bart model on one machine with `serialize = TRUE`

```
bart <- bartMachine(X, Y, 
                    k = 2,
                    num_trees = 50, 
                    use_missing_data = TRUE,
                    serialize = TRUE,
                    verbose = FALSE)
```

and save it (`save(bart, file = 'bart.bartmachine')`), I cannot open it on a different machine (`load(file = 'bart.bartmachine')`), receiving the error:

```
Error in check_serialization(bart_machine) : 
  This bartMachine object was loaded from an R image but was not serialized.
  Please build bartMachine using the option "serialize = TRUE" next time.
```

This is consistent in both directions:

- Create and Save on Machine 1 -> load on Machine 2
- Create and Save on Machine 2 -> load on Machine 1

I have the seed set and cores set to 1:

```
set.seed(123)
set_bart_machine_num_cores(1)
```

Any thoughts on how to make this compatible? I could work around by saving machine specific versions but trying to avoid this.